# Presenting 2D array as a tree

Tags: c, algorithm, pseudocode

I have the following problem:

I have an array of n x n integers where n is the power of 2 (1, 2, 4...). We can imagine that the whole array (when n > 1) is divided into 4 pieces:

```
A B
D C
```

Each piece can be divided similarly, if it hasn't got 1 element. I'd like to present this array as a tree, where each node holds:

```
   a) integer, when the "square" cannot be divided futher
   or
   b) 4 nodes, corresponding to each piece: A,B,C,D
```

I have all the integers in the 2D array and I want to write a function to create a tree. I've only managed to create a node structure so far:

```
 struct node {
  int number;
  struct node *child[4];
};
```

The problem is, I can't find the way to traverse the array and, in the same time, create nodes and assign values to them.

Could you please support me with a pseudocode of this procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create the layers of your tree from the bottom up:

1. Start by creating an n x n array of nodes and assign the numbers to the nodes. This array will contain the leaves of the tree.
2. Then create a new two dimensional array of nodes with dimensions n/2 * n/2. For each node, assign the respective nodes of the original array as children. So for the node with coordinates (x,y) in the new array, you will assign the children (x*2,y*2), (x*2+1,y*2), (x*2,y*2+1), and (x*2+1,y*2+1) in the old array.
3. Repeat the last step recursively on the new arary until the array has dimensions 1 x 1.

Thus, you end up with a single node representing the root of your tree.

Comment: This is so elegant solution.

Comment: Good approach, I provided the exact opposite way, from root to leaves

Answer (score 1):

I would like to present a top down approach:

It is best to define a function that creates the nodes for you. the function is responsible to create all of its own children recursively.

Only the leafs will have valuable information for their `int number;` field.

You hold all of the information in a 2D array and you pass in the appropriate lower and upper x and y coordinates for each node in the tree.

Here is the C code that describes my method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 4


struct treeNode{
int number;
struct treeNode * A,*B,*C,*D;
//A top left,
//B top right
//C bottom right
//D bottom left
};
struct treeNode* createNode(int input[][DIM], int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    struct treeNode * output = malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode));
    output->number=-1; //arbitrary value gets overwritten in leafs
    output->A=NULL;
    output->B=NULL;
    output->C=NULL;
    output->D=NULL;

    if(x1==x2)// single integer
    {
       output->number=input[x1][y1];
    }
    else
    {
    int midX = x1 + (x2-x1)/2;
    int midY = y1 + (y2-y1)/2;

    output->A = createNode(input,     x1, midX,     y1, midY);
    output->B = createNode(input,     x1, midX, 1+midY,   y2);
    output->C = createNode(input, 1+midX,   x2, 1+midY,   y2);
    output->D = createNode(input, 1+midX,   x2,     y1, midY);
    }
    return output;
};
```

Since your tree is dynamically allocated, you will need an elegant way to free the memory recursively:

```
void deleteTree(struct treeNode* t)
{
    if(t==NULL) return; //NULL passed in
    if(t->A==NULL) //leaf
    {
        free(t);
        return;
    }
    deleteTree(t->A);
    deleteTree(t->B);
    deleteTree(t->C);
    deleteTree(t->D);
    free(t);//free memory for pointer;
}
```

And inside your main function you have:

```
int main()
{

    int A[DIM][DIM]={0};

    int i=0, counter=1;
    for(;i<DIM;++i)
    {
        int j=0;

        for(; j<DIM; ++j) A[i][j]=counter++;
    }
    struct treeNode* root = createNode(A,0,DIM-1,0,DIM-1);

    struct treeNode* nonLeaf = root->B;

    struct treeNode* leaf = nonLeaf->B;
    printf("%d", leaf->number);


    deleteTree(root);

    return 0;
}
```